# Can mitmproxy auto accept requests?

Tags: proxy

I've been using mitmproxy (http://mitmproxy.org/) to debug requests between my app and server. I know that 'a' accepts and 'A' accepts all, but is there a way to have it autoaccept all the calls and allow me browse through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have an intercept filter set.  Hit 'i' and clear out the Intercept filter. Without that filter set mitmproxy will behave as you wish it. You can use 'l' to set a limit filter which will only show the flows you are interested in. Set the intercept filter again when you're ready to intercept.

Comment: Thanks, the 'l' option was what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that in mitmproxy 3.0.4, `f` is now the keybinding for setting a filter that limits the flows you see.